# What is the difference between the types "string" and "func() string"?

Tags: string, function, go, types

I am very new to programming in general let alone Go... currently I have been experimenting serving some content via HTTP, and [for reasons] I have a string that I want to store in a separate package, and serve it back to my main project via a function call.
however I am getting an error (in various forms depending on how I change the code up):

"mismatched types string and func() string"

here is the 'data' package

```
package encodedjs
var base64EncodedJS string
func ReadEncodedJS() string {
 return base64EncodedJS
}
func init() {
 base64EncodedJS = "data:text/javascript;base64,largestring_blah_blah_blah=="
}
```

...then the main code calling it

```
package main
import ( 
 "./encodedjs" 
)
func main() {
 js := "some text to simply show one way I've tried" + encodedjs.ReadEncodedJS
}
```

Comment: Consider taking the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) to get a foundation in Go language and syntax. It doesn't take long and will help a lot in understanding the basics.

Comment: I FORGOT the ()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `encodedjs.ReadEncodedJS` [qualified identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers) just denotes the function, if used as-is, it is just a function value (e.g. can be assigned to variables of the same function type).

If you want to call it and use its return value, use parentheses, e.g. `encodedjs.ReadEncodedJS()`. This is detailed in [Spec: Calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls).

Since you want to concatenate `string` values, you have to call it:

```
js := "some text to simply show one way I've tried" + encodedjs.ReadEncodedJS()
```

Comment: Thank you, I am irritated that I forgot that, I mean I worked on this for an embarrassing long time to not have that ever click in my head... and it sits right next to other correct function calls quite literally in front of my face.

Answer (score 1):

`string` is a `string` and `func() string` is a function that returns a `string`. Looks to me that `encodedjs.ReadEncodedJS` is the latter and to get the `string` that it returns you would write `encodedjs.ReadEncodedJS()`.

Comment: Thank you, I am irritated that I forgot that, I mean I worked on this for an embarrassing long time to not have that ever click in my head... and it sits right next to other correct function calls quite literally in front of my face.